# Add favorite with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, object

I am learning symfony.
I try to save favorite when I click on a link and when I click again on the link, I wish I could remove the favorite in DB.
When clicking, I do have a new row in my database. 
If I click again, it add a new one and don't  erase the row.
This is what i have done in my controller:

```
 public function addFavorite(EntityManagerInterface $manager, PostRepository $postRepository, Post $post)
    {
        $favorite = $postRepository->findOneBy(['content' => $post,'author' => $this->getUser()
        ]);

        if (is_null($favorite)) {
            $favorite = new Favorite();
            $favorite
                ->setPost($post)
                ->setUser($this->getUser());
            $manager->persist($favorite);
            $manager->flush();

            return $this->render('favorite/index.html.twig');
        } else {
            $manager->remove($favorite);
            $manager->flush();

            return $this->render('favorite/index.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

From what i understand, the problem is that $favorite is still NULL and i don't understand why...
If someone could help me, thanks !

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you don't request the good entity. I don't really know your entities, but I think this could be more logical :

```
public function addFavorite(EntityManagerInterface $manager, FavoriteRepository $favoriteRepository, Post $post)
    {
        $favorite = $favoriteRepository->findOneBy([
            'post' => $post,
            'user' => $this->getUser()
        ]);

        if (!$favorite) {
            $favorite = new Favorite();
            $favorite
                ->setPost($post)
                ->setUser($this->getUser());
            $manager->persist($favorite);
        } else {
            $manager->remove($favorite);
        }

        $manager->flush();

        return $this->render('favorite/index.html.twig');
    }
```